# Prevent text from moving on hover

Tags: html, css

The span appears when hovering over the container div, but it pushes the previous text to the left, how can I prevent that?

The height, width and border on the wrapper are just there to demonstrate the effect.

```css
#wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.element {
  display: inline-block;
}

.element > span {
  display: none;
}

.element:hover > span {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="element">Some Sample Text <span>Some hovered text</span></div>
  <br>
  <div class="element">Some Sample Text <span>Some hovered text</span></div>
  <br> ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `position: absolute;` to the `span`, also add `white-space: nowrap;` to the container to prevent wrapping as needed.

```css
#wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.element {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap; /* NEW */
}

.element > span {
  display: none;
  position: absolute; /* NEW */
}

.element:hover > span {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="element">Some Sample Text <span>Some hovered text</span></div>
  <br>
  <div class="element">Some Sample Text <span>Some hovered text</span></div>
  <br> ...
</div>
```